# Application can save files when run manually but not when run by Task Scheduler

Tags: c#, windows, windows-server-2008, scheduler

I have a simple command line application which creates a CSV dump of a database every night and sends an email. The file it creates is saved on a mapped network drive which I refer to in my `app.config` like so:

```
<add key="Path" value="X:\Path\To\Folder" />
```

Everything works fine if I run it from the command line, but when it is run by Task Scheduler, it throws the following exception:

> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'X:\Path\To\Folder\File.csv'.

The account the task runs as has admin privileges and I've additionally tried running it as the domain admin but to no avail.

The system is running on Windows Server 2008 R2, though I'm not sure if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this MSDN forum post](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d54b9e17-6815-46b4-a9c8-032125890647/scheduled-task-cannot-write-csv-file?forum=winservermanager):

> ...mapped drives won't exist when no one is logged on so always best to use a UNC path as in;
>
> **\\servername\sharename**

So changing the path string to be:

```
<add key="Path" value="\\Server\Share\Path\To\Folder" />
```

will make sure that drive is accessible even if the maps aren't.

Comment: I had the same problem with a local drive on a Windows Server 2003 VM hosted in Azure. I had to replace D:\path with \\192.168.0.4\d$\path. Then it worked.